# SpriteKit coordinates messed up

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sprite

I am trying to add sprites to my SKScene, but the coordinate system seems to be weird. The [0, 0] point is in the middle of the screen and not in the lower left corner like it should be. I have no idea how this could have happened as I have tried correcting using a variety of methods I have found in similar questions. 
Here is my GameViewController class:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {


    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        if let scene = MenuScene(fileNamed: "MenuScene"){                    
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
            view.presentScene(scene)
        }

        view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        view.showsFPS = true
        view.showsNodeCount = true

    }
}
```

I have tried changed the scaleMode which only changed the scale of sprites and didn't fix the issue. I have also tried changing MenuScene(fileNamed: ) to  MenuScene(size: view.bounds.size) which gave me errors. If I am missing any details, please ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is happening because by default, SKScenes have an anchorPoint of (0.5, 0.5). This places the point (0,0) in the centre. If you're looking to change the anchorPoint to the bottom-left, add this to the beginning of didMoveToView:

```
self.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
```

Or initialize the scene with that anchorPoint before presenting it (from GameViewController):

```
scene.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
```

Or change it in the scene editor.

FYI: `CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)` is the same as `CGPoint.zero`

Personally, I find it easier to build the scene outwards from the centre because it makes symmetry easier and laying out HUD easier, instead of from a corner, which results in building the scene from the corner, potentially creating difficulties.

Comment: Thanks. It worked like you said. I prefer to have 0, 0 at the corner because it allows you to use size.width or size.height * % of screen, when position nodes with code.

Comment: @CarterGrycko No prob. It's all about preference